# How to count duplicates from ListBox and show the number of duplicated items beside it?

Tags: c#, listbox, duplicates

So I have a button, where if you click it, it adds `"Candy"` to a `listbox`, how do I make it so, if another item with the same name is being added, instead of adding it in a new line, update the first line to show x2, 3, 4, etc. Is that possible or would I have to make another `Listbox` and match the index? I've tried the following with another `listbox` and an int variable.

```
private void btnCandy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstProducts.Items.Add("Candy");
        foreach (var item in lstProducts.Items)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == "Candy")
            {
                ++Productcount;
                lstQuantity.Items.Add(Productcount);
                if (Productcount > 1)
                {
                    lstQuantity.Items.Insert(lstProducts.Items.IndexOf("Candy"), Productcount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have u done so far?? Question is not very clear to understand

Comment: Could you please include the snippet that adds "Candy" to a listbox

Comment: I have a button, and a listbox. When I click the button it adds the string "Candy" into the listbox.

Comment: Can you post your code you done so far?

Comment: I've added a snippet of what I tried to attempt.

Comment: @AlexGomes see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Use:

```
private void btnCandy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "Candy";
    bool isExist = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < lstProducts.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var s = lstProducts.Items[i].ToString();
        if (s.StartsWith(query))
        {
            if (s == query)
            {
                lstProducts.Items[i] = query + "x2";
                isExist = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Escape your plain text before use with regex
                var pattern = Regex.Escape(query);
                // Check if s has this formnat: queryx2, queryx3, queryx4, ...
                Match m = Regex.Match(s, "^" + pattern + @"x(\d+)$");
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    lstProducts.Items[i] = query + "x" + (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) + 1);
                    isExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isExist) lstProducts.Items.Add(query);
}
```

**Note:**

- `\d` mean any digit (0 - 9)

Comment: This was pretty close, it adds x2 if it exists but after x2, it creates a newline and repeats

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly. I've never really worked with Regex before but this is some really nice code. Thank-you.

Comment: I've given you the selected answer, I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶e̶n̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶l̶y̶ ̶v̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ you have my 1up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to iterate through listbox items and if I find "Candy" then take that index and update title.

```
private void btnCandy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (var item in lstProducts.Items)
    {
        if (item.ToString().StartsWith("Candy"))
        {
            // update item title
            found = true;
            break; // no need to continue
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        lstProducts.Items.Add("Candy");
    }
}
```

this way you are not going to add duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code to help you. Add this to your button click event:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string item in listbox1.Items)
{
     If (item == textbox1.text) //textbox1.text contains the string such as 'candy'
    {
         i++;
         listbox1.Items.Remove(item);
         listbox1.Items.Add(textbox1.text + " " + i.ToString());
    }
}
```

You may have to reset the counter as needed.